# How can I unify a list?

Tags: python, list

this is my code for now in python

```
l = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

for elements in list, l copy the list

```
g = [x for x in l]
```

insert g into list l after element 2

```
l.insert(2,g)
print(l)

>>>[0,1,[0,1,2,3,4,5],2,3,4,5]
```

I want to it read

```
>>>[0,1,0,1,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use slice assingment:

```
l[2:2] = g
```

This replaces the slice `[2:2]` (which is empty) with the elements of `g`; essentially this inserts the contents of `g` after index `2`:

```
>>> l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> g = [x for x in l]
>>> l[2:2] = g
>>> l
[0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```